# How to convert a Sqlite database to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I have searched a lot for this subject,but failed.Therefore,I have found some pythone and ruby scripts but I know nothing of those languages.

I want to know if there is any solution to convert a sqlite database to mysql using php or any other softwares.

Another problem I have is to convert Persian words and also English phonetics.Both of them change to undefined words on conversion

I appreciate any response

Comment: @splash58 yes...I have seen that topic.but I couldn't find the way.I have said I know nothing of pythone or ruby

Comment: gfrom there - https://dbconvert.com/sqlite/mysql/?DB=10

Comment: Yeap but that software has a limitation to only 50 records.furthermore,I don't have 149 dollars to buy that...:((

Comment: I used navicat to convert my databases and I succeeded but as I said in my question it has problem in converting phonetics and persian words...

Comment: @Mr.NaViD have you try [dumping your db from sqlite cli](http://alvinalexander.com/android/sqlite-dump-backup-database-file-how) and check if the troublesome characters are outputted correctly?

Comment: thank you dear @bangbambang.Yes everuthing is right on my sqlite databse.And I'm using it in an android application correctly!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer!!

You can import your Sqlite database into Navicat for Sqlite. Then you can export it as .CSV file.If you import it in MySQL then everything is right.